# Xcode cannot find symbol for particular source

Tags: ios, ffmpeg

I have an iOS project utilizing ffmpeg. The library is pre-built and copied to the project tree

`ffmpeg/
├── include
│   ├── libavcodec
│   ├── libavdevice
│   ├── libavfilter
│   ├── libavformat
│   ├── libavresample
│   ├── libavutil
│   ├── libpostproc
│   ├── libswresample
│   └── libswscale
└── lib
    ├── libavcodec.a
    ├── libavdevice.a
    ├── libavfilter.a
    ├── libavformat.a
    ├── libavresample.a
    ├── libavutil.a
    ├── libpostproc.a
    ├── libswresample.a
    └── libswscale.a`

`.h` files are omitted above for clarity.

In the `Build Setting`, the **Header Search Paths** and **Library Search Paths** are added respectively.

When compiling, Xcode complains about tens of `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64`, all about ffmpeg. All the errors come from the same source file. And in another source file, no error is given though it also utilize ffmpeg.